# Can I put one fragment into another fragment which is in FragmentActivity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a FragmentActivity this activity has a Fragment this Fragment consist from widgets and fragment which is defined in xml.

When I start the activity it crashes

```
10-19 13:27:57.470: E/AndroidRuntime(16701): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class fragment
```

Is it posible to have nested fragments, or I can put fragments only in FragmentActivity?

EDIT:
this is xml of fragment which is located in FragmentActivity ViewPager

Programm crashes in this file on inflating

```
        <com.ssbs.sw.SWE.widget.SeekBarWidget
            android:id="@+id/pa_outlet_characteristics_trading_stocks"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:max="999999"
            android:text="@string/label_outlet_characteristics_trading_stocks" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/pa_outlet_characteristics_spinners"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            class="com.ssbs.sw.SWE.pure.outlet.pages.characteristics.view.components.SpinnersFragment"
            tools:layout="@layout/pf_characteristics_custperday_spinner" />

        <com.ssbs.sw.SWE.widget.SpinnerWidget
            android:id="@+id/pa_outlet_characteristics_proximity_factor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="?spinerBackground"
            widget:label="@string/label_outlet_characteristics_proximity_factor"
            widget:popupDialogTheme="@style/ActivityDialog"
            widget:spinnerTemplate="@layout/widget_spinner" />
```

**UPDATE**

Support of nested fragments was added in support library from 11 version

> Support Package, revision 11 (November 2012) 
>   Changes for v4 support library:
>   User Interface 
>   Added support for nested Fragment classes.
>   Added improvements to FragmentManager debugging.
>   .......

[Nested Fragments documentation](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the support API I don't know but normally it's not possible to create nested fragment : you can create a fragment from another one, but this fragment will communicate only with the Activity that created the original fragment (if it's not clear, tell me)

**EDIT :**

As for why it crashes, if it's not a nested fragment, I don't have a clue. Maybe you should try creating it and adding it to your layout programmatically

Comment: What does you mean "fragment will communicate only with the Activity that created the original fragment "?

Comment: I mean that you can't pass an instance of another fragment to your fragment as it won't be remembered by your Bundle arguments (it's not Parcelable), so for example if you turn your screen your app will crash as it will have to rebuild your fragment, and this fragment won't have any reference to the fragment you want to communicate with (complicated, yes !)

Comment: And it's not the case with your activity since in the end, even if you crate your fragment from another fragment, it's the original Activity that really creates it (someone stops me if I'm wrong, I'm not 100% sure of what I say). So your fragment always has a reference to the activity that created it.

Comment: The problem is that i can`t even create this fragment/

Comment: as I said in my edit, maybe you should try creating it and adding it to your layout programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Nested fragments are not allowed. (depends on the version).

**EDIT** - Previously it was not supported, but it was added from version 11 as mention in post above : https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html#NestedFragments